# Adding meta and styles to html document with XMLDocument class

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am creating html document with XMLDocument class and VB.NET pretty successfully.
Code look like this:

```
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
Dim xmlRoot As XmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("html")
xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlRoot)

Dim xmlHead As XmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("head")
xmlRoot.AppendChild(xmlHead)

Dim xmlTitle As XmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("title")
xmlTitle.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("myDocument"))
xmlHead.AppendChild(xmlTitle)
etc...
```

Now I can't find a way to write meta and styles (and scripts in general) in head section of document with XmlDocument class and VB.NET (or C#) to get such code in created html document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type='text/css'>
<!--
td{font-family: Arial Narrow; font-size: 10pt;}
.adress {font-family:Arial Narrow; font-size: 10pt;}
tr.borders td {border-top:1pt solid black; border-bottom:1pt solid black;}
--->
</style>
```

Please help to write that properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue in the same fashion as you started

```
Dim xmlMeta As XmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("meta")

Dim xmlAttrHttpEquiv As XmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("http-equiv")
xmlAttrHttpEquiv.Value = "Content-Language"

Dim xmlAttrContent As XmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("content")
xmlAttrContent.Value = "en"

xmlMeta.Attributes.Append(xmlAttrHttpEquiv)
xmlMeta.Attributes.Append(xmlAttrContent)
xmlHead.AppendChild(xmlMeta)
```

And so on...

If you want to set text inside style element you could use the elemets InnerText property.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that helps. But now I'm wondering is here any rational reason for doing this? I can easily make my html document with simple string concatenations and usual string operations with much less coding.

Comment: Yea, infact the XmlDocument does not work very well with html.
Most html-pages would refuse to load into XmlDocumet as they are not fully compatable.

I would suggest that you look into the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)